# What is the overview belief of the SDA regarding the Gift of Tongues?

Tags: acts, 1-corinthians, spiritual-gifts, seventh-day-adventists, speaking-in-tongues

One of the fundamental beliefs of the SDA is the belief in ([Spiritual Gifts and Ministries No 17](https://www.adventist.org/spiritual-gifts-and-ministries/)) but what is intriguing is whenever they list these gifts in their commentaries the gift of tongues is always conspicuous by its absence from the list.

The gift of tongues is clearly articulated as one of the gifts of the church in the New Testament

Mark 16:17 ESV

> 17 And these signs will accompany those who believe: in my name they will cast out demons; they will speak in new tongues;

Acts 2:4 ESV

> 4 And they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak in other tongues as the Spirit gave them utterance.

1 Corinthians 12:10 esv

> 10 to another the working of miracles, to another prophecy, to another the ability to distinguish between spirits, to another various kinds of tongues, to another the interpretation of tongues.

Why does the SDA seem to sideline this gift?

Answer (score 1):

The spiritual gift of speaking in tongues is not sidelined.  the link you provided also has a sublist that is more complete. You will see it [here](https://www.adventist.org/spiritual-gifts-and-ministries/#types-of-gifts)

However, the gift of speaking in tongues is vague and is often found in Pentecostal churches. The Seventh-day Adventist Church does not see this as a usual manifestation of the gift. you can see early Adventist pioneers writing on the subject [here](https://m.egwwritings.org/en/book/954.66#67)

This stigma to the Pentecostal experience is very tangible within the church.  Generally, the church would be considered more academic than experiential. The stigma also affects the Gift of prophecy, which the Adventist Church Holds only to specialised prophets i.e. Ellen White.

Personally, as a Seventh-day Adventist, I have had heard the testimony of the following manifestations the gift of tongues.

1. The gift of tongues used and interpreted over a close Adventist friend (in a Pentecostal service)
2. The Gift of tongues heard by people who could only hear in another language (Spanish) spoken by a minister who could only speak in another (English). This is similar to what is recorded in Acts 2.